# How can I use Solr subquery similar to rdbms subqueries?

Tags: solr, subquery, solr-query-syntax

I need to run a query in Solr that contains another query as terms of the main query!

Something like this in the RDBMS SQL:

```
select name from movie
where movie.writer in (
    select director from movie where producer = 'XXX'
)
```

Is there any way to do this is Solr?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
This is possible using "join" in Solr.
Following is the solution for my answered example:

```
fl=name&  
q={!join from=writer to=director}+producer:XXX
```

Also a filter query can be added. This filter will affect the result of join and query.
Thanks to Ramzy.

Comment: what about just mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can try filter, something like this..

```
q=movie:name
fq=(writer:writer_name AND producer:Producer_name)
```

also the data that you put into a Solr index is flat or denormalized. 
So take the suquery field values and put them in an AND part of the query to Solr.

```
q=(movie:name AND writer:Writer_name AND producer:Producer_name)
```

Comment: In the example, I want to retreive movies that their writer is the director of movies that "XXX" produces! A simple "and" filrer can't result such list.

Comment: I'm searching for a way to implement my query as a one phase query, however I implemented it with two phases queries (putting the result of inner query in the main query).

Comment: I would like to how you tried and whats the result? whats the document structure you have ?